# geom_point overlay on top of geom_line in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a screenshot of a graph made in another software that creates a scatter plot **on top of** a line graph, with the line hidden where the scatter plot is. This is what I am going for in R.

[image]
When I run the following code on my graph and data:

```
dput(my_df)
structure(list(lastFinancingYear = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 
2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018), raiseMedVal = c(5.33287671232877, 
5.03424657534247, 4.96986301369863, 7.36986301369863, 6.44383561643836, 
7.73835616438356, 8.4958904109589, 9.9054794520548, 9.43013698630137
), foundMedVal = c(11.0821917808219, 10.5178082191781, 8.62191780821918, 
10.2520547945205, 10.9643835616438, 10.9342465753425, 12.9945205479452, 
13.5397260273973, 12.6301369863014)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

my_df %>% ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = lastFinancingYear, y = raiseMedVal), size = 1.0, color = "#DDBB7B") +
  geom_point(aes(x = lastFinancingYear, y = raiseMedVal), shape = 1, size = 3.0, color = "#DDBB7B") +
  geom_line(aes(x = lastFinancingYear, y = foundMedVal), size = 1.0)
```

... then i get a graph that looks like this:

[image]

Where the scatter markers are present and on top of the line, **but the line is not hidden behind the marker**, and also the scatter markers do not have a bold/thick enough marker. I am not sure how to fix these, and any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a few tweaks to get this working:

- Use one of the filled point shapes, like shape 21. You can check what these are with `example("points")` and going to the 3rd plot.
- Use `fill = "white"` (or some other colour) now that you're using a filled shape.
- Order of your geoms matters - later geoms go on top so move `geom_point()` to the end.
- Increase the `stroke` to increase the border size of the points

Updated code:

```
my_df %>% ggplot() +
    geom_line(aes(x = lastFinancingYear, y = raiseMedVal), size = 1.0, color = "#DDBB7B") +
    geom_line(aes(x = lastFinancingYear, y = foundMedVal), size = 1.0) +
    geom_point(aes(x = lastFinancingYear, y = raiseMedVal), size = 3.0, color = "#DDBB7B",
               shape = 21, 
               stroke = 2.0,
               fill = "white")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: all 3 answers here were great - accepting this because it involves changing the least of my code. Although the geom_pointline is cool too

Answer (score 7):

I created `geom_pointline` for this exact situation (with some flair):

```
library(lemon)
library(tidyr)

my_df %>%
 gather(stat, val, raiseMedVal, foundMedVal) %>%
 ggplot(aes(lastFinancingYear, val, colour=stat)) + 
 geom_pointline(distance=0.1, fill='white', shape=21, size=3.5, stroke=2, linesize=2)
```

Notice that I am changing the dataframe to a *long format*, such that the colour is linked to a variable and not hardcoded. Secondly, the aesthetics are compounded in the main `ggplot` call to avoid redundant settings.
(And my apoligies that `distance` had to be 0.1, not 0).

[image]

To control the colours and appearence of legend, use the usual ggplot2 functions, i.e. `scale_colour_manual` (or `_hue`, or `_brewer`, or...).

*Edit:* Wow, I learnt about using `stroke` to control the border width of the points. Thanks @Marius.

Comment: this answer is equally as good as the accepted answer and im sorry i cannot accept both

Comment: Perfectly understandable you choose the answer that require least change. :)

Answer (score 2):

Slight variation but same idea...

```
my_df %>% ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = lastFinancingYear, y = raiseMedVal), size = 0.8, color = "#DDBB7B") +
  geom_point(aes(x = lastFinancingYear, y = raiseMedVal), 
             shape = 21, size = 1.0, stroke = 1.5, color = "#DDBB7B", fill = "white") +

  geom_line(aes(x = lastFinancingYear, y = foundMedVal), size = 0.8) +
  geom_point(aes(x = lastFinancingYear, y = foundMedVal), 
             shape = 21, size = 1.5, stroke = 1.5, color = "black", fill = "white")
```

[image]

### Programmatic approach

If you're planning to use this format a lot, you might want to make a function to simplify it.

```
spotted_lines <- function(x_var, y_var, my_color = "black") {
  list(geom_line(aes(x  = x_var, y = y_var), size = 0.8, color = my_color),
       geom_point(aes(x = x_var, y = y_var), shape = 21, size = 1.0, 
            stroke = 1.5, color = my_color, fill = "white")
  )
}
```

Then you can call that function inside your ggplot call and it will make both the lines and points geometry, saving you time and reducing the potential for mistakes.

```
my_df %>% ggplot() +
  spotted_lines(x_var = my_df$lastFinancingYear, y_var = my_df$foundMedVal) +
  spotted_lines(x_var = my_df$lastFinancingYear, y_var = my_df$raiseMedVal,
                my_color = "#DDBB7B")
```

Comment: If you add dark gray grid lines, the figure will be spot on to the original. :)